# Find vector element in second vector

Tags: c++, stl

Given two vectors of integers, how to determinate if there's some element from 1st vector is present in 2nd one?

Comment: Are they sorted, can they be sorted in place or do they have to stay in their current order?

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: do you have complexity constraints?

Comment: they are not sorted, but I don't care to have a linear run time, since the vectors are resonable small. I justr want to avail handwritten for in for.

Comment: Well you are stuck with linear runtime - C++ algorithms are not magical.

Comment: fair enough - then I'd go with Brian's solution, who managed to get in while I was still looking up the definition of `set_intersection` :-)

Comment: @Neil - you may be able to improve on it if you copy one or both vectors into a set

Comment: I think that sorting both is overkill. I reckon you're looking at O( N * M ) vs. O( N log N + M log N ), which is O( (N + M) * log N ) although I may have missed a better technique.

Comment: @Phil Indeed. Or simply sort the vector, but I thought the OP didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess something like this should work:

```
std::vector<int> v1,v2;
if(std::find_first_of(v2.begin(),v2.end(),v1.begin(),v1.end()) != v2.end())
   std::cout << "found!\n";
```

Comment: Although it may appear worse in complexity `O(v1.size() * v2.size())`, it doesn't really matter on small sets, and you don't have to modify (sort) your vectors beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

You could take the [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) of both vectors, and then check if the resulting intersection is empty:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::set_intersection(v1.begin()
  , v1.end()
  , v2.begin()
  , v2.end()
  , std::back_inserter(v3));
bool containsElements = !v3.empty();
```

`set_intersection` can be found in `#include <algorithm>`

For `set_intersection` to work, both vectors must first be sorted.

Comment: It's worth noting that v1 and v2 must be sorted for this to work.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should prefer `v3.empty()` to `v3.size() == 0`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey and @Matthie M.:  I added both of these, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
bool contains(const std::vector<int>& vec, int val){
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it){
        if(*it==val){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool contains(const std::vector<int>& from, const std::vector<int>& in){
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it=from.begin(); it!=from.end(); ++it){
        if(contains(in, *it)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Example
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;

a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(1);
b.push_back(0);
b.push_back(1);

bool contains = contains(a, b);
```

Comment: this is equal to handwritten for in for. I' looking for a STL way solution